# LEGO item number for white racing wedge with printed #3

Tags: part-identification

What is the LEGO item number for this piece?  What sets does it go to?

I'm not having much luck searching for it.

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's Part 6153, either [6153apb01](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6153apb01) or [6153apb05](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6153apb05) depending on whether there are stars on the sides. Both seem to originate from different editions of the [Water Jet, Set 6517-1](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6517-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D).